# Mac Services in Firefox Deprecated?

Tags: macos, firefox, applescript, macos-sierra, automator

For just a few months, I've used a Mac Automator Workflow that wraps the HTML "em" tags around my selected text. It's to tag text in my Google Calendar that then runs through an API to turn it into a schedule of events in a web page.

I would just highlight the word "big" in: "this is a big thing"

And run this brief script:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    return "<em>" & input & "</em>"
end run
```

And it's now

```
"this is a <em>big</em> thing"
```

But this week, after the latest update to Firefox (53.0), trying to run the service return the error message:

> There was a problem with the input to the Service  [Show Workflow] [OK]

Is support for Services another feature that Firefox is removing, just like JavaScript?

Is there possibly a Preference I can set to make it run again?

Or am I going to have to learn to create my own WebExtensions to avoid having to type tags by hand?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Firefox 53. See [Bug 1361116: Services menu in os x does not send pasteboard data to the service](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1361116), where it is reported to be fixed in Firefox 54.

Comment: By the way, Mac-specific questions can be asked at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com). See, for example: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefox

Comment: Thanks. Once again, it's a matter of knowing what terms to search for.

Comment: @MarkMcD Don't forget to mark the answer as "answered" if this answered the question for you.

Comment: I upvoted and checked the green check mark. I think that marks it as "answered."